# Sort Average In A file

Tags: python, file, sorting

I have a file with 3 scores for each person. Each person has their own row. I want to use these scores, and get the average of all 3 of them. There scores are separated by tabs and in descending order. For example:

```
tam     10    6   11
tom     3    7    3
tim     5    4    6
```

these people would come out with an average of:

```
tam    9
tom    5
tim    4
```

I want these to be able to print to the python shell, however not be saved to the file.

```html
with open("file.txt") as file1:
    d = {}
    count = 0
    for line in file1:
        column = line.split()
        names = column[0]
        average = (int(column[1].strip()) + int(column[2].strip()) + int(column[3].strip()))/3

        count = 0
        while count < 3:
            d.setdefault(names, []).append(average)
            count = count + 1
    for names, v in sorted(d.items()):
        averages = (sum(v)/3)
        print(names,average)
    averageslist=[]
    averageslist.append(averages)
```

My code only finds the first persons average and outputs it for all of them. I also want it to be descending in order of averages.

Comment: `tom`'s average is 4.33 instead of 5 as you write in your example output. `(3+7+3)/3 == 4.33`

Comment: And `tim`'s average is 5 instead of 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code that parses your file into a list of (name, average) tuples and prints every entry of the by average sorted list:

```
import operator
with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = []
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split()
        name = parts[0]
        vals = parts[1:]
        avg = sum(int(x) for x in vals)/len(vals)
        data.append((name, avg))
    for person in sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
        print("{} {}".format(*person))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct.You are calculating `average` in the first step.So need of `sum(v)/3` again.Try this

```
with open("file.txt") as file1:
    d = {}
    count = 0
    for line in file1:
        column = line.split()
        names = column[0]
        average = (int(column[1].strip()) + int(column[2].strip()) + int(column[3].strip()))/3
        d[names] = average
    for names, v in sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True): #increasing order==>sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[1])
        print(names,v)
#output
('tam', 9)
('tim', 5)
('tom', 4)
```

**To sort by name**

```
for names, v in sorted(d.items()):
    print(names,v)

#output
('tam', 9)
('tim', 5)
('tom', 4)
```

Comment: Your solution does not sort by average but by name.

Comment: I think OP need sort by `avg` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant sort by average, was a bit vague there

Comment: Yes I think so. The wrong example output he shows is sorted by average in decreasing order and his last line is  `I also want it to be descending in order.` but sorted by name it's in ascending order. He is just kucky that ascending order by name is the same as descending order by average for his data.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
from operator import itemgetter
with open("file.txt") as file1:
    d = {}
    count = 0
    for line in file1:
        column = line.split()
        names = column[0]
        average = (int(column[1].strip()) + int(column[2].strip()) + int(column[3].strip()))/3

        count = 0
        d.setdefault(names, []).append(average)
    for names,v in sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True):
        print(names,v)
```

Comment: Your solution does not sort by average but by name.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this:

```
averages = (sum(v)/3)
print(names,average)
```

Notice that on the first line you are computing `averages` (with an s at the end) and on the next line you are printing `average` (without an s).